# Scrolling to anchors unpredictable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a simple vertical timeline. You can click up or down to scroll it little by little but I also wanted to have it jump, smooth scroll, to anchors. This somewhat works but the behavior is unpredictable.

This isn't usually difficult but something new for me is that the scrolling behavior is inside a div so the whole page shouldn't be moving.

You can try it in the fiddle. Clicking random buttons will sometimes bring you to the right spot, other times it will just scroll to a random place.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejs06003/a489mweh/)

Here is the basic Jquery.

```
var step = 280;
var scrolling = false;

$(".scrollUp").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#timeline").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
})

$(".scrollDown").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#timeline").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
})

$('.timelineButton').click(function () {
    $('#timeline').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: try to give the headings in the content id's and then scroll to the id's instead increasing pixels :)

Comment: Sorry @OliverF., I am not sure I understand. I thought I was trying to scroll to the id's using the href anchors. Am I confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need fixing :

- Use `.position().top` (relative to offset parent) instead of `.offset().top` (relative to document)
- Specify the offset parent by styling the `#timeline` container with `position: relative`
- Because `.position()` returns dynamically calculated values, `.position().top` will be the value-you-want minus the current-scrollTop. Therefore you need to add the current-scrollTop back on.

**CSS**

```css
#timeline {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
$('.timelineButton').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#timeline').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).position().top + $('#timeline').scrollTop()
    }, 2000);
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a489mweh/5/)**

Comment: This seems to kill the Up/Down buttons and is jumpy instead of a smooth scroll. Unless I am implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: Works fine for me. I've added a link to updated fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for you help. This fixed my problem. I appreciate you adding the Demo Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add Ids to each div & use that ID like href="#ID". This will scroll window to that particular section ID given in href

Comment: This doesn't perform the animation though.

Comment: Right, there is no animation / smooth scroll and then you have to click the back button x number of times for each time you click a bookmark.

Comment: @HarjeetSingh how is that in any way helpful? You've just copied an unrelated fiddle from somewhere else.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I shared this because this relates to problem faced by Eric.

Comment: @HarjeetSingh, thanks. This is semi-related and I wish it was that easy. Your example scrolls the whole page. I want it to just scroll the div with the content while the page doesn't move.

Comment: @Eric.18, I have made some changes, can you please check now. I made the sections scrollable only

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$('.timelineButton').click(function () {
    if($('#timeline').is(':animated')){}else{
      $('#timeline').animate({
          scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 2000);
      return false;
    }
});
```

**.is(':animated')** will be tell you if the element is animating, if not, animate it.
It prevent the unpredictable jumps.

**EDIT**
Best way to prevent this is: 
**.stop().animate**

```
$('.timelineButton').click(function () {
    $('#timeline').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT V2**
Check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a489mweh/3/
I have to put the position offset of each elements in an array, becouse every animate in timeline change the offset.top of each element.
Check the data-arr="0" over each button, to tell the array what position of the element have to retrieve.
Tell me if works.
Cheers

Comment: Roy, I tried it and it is still weird. In the fiddle, original or implementing you code, try clicking random buttons and it will scroll up when it should go down and vice-versa.